# OpenLdap ACL Admin Group rights

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

Hi I have been trying to achieve Admin and operator level ACL to no avail.
So far I've got

```
access to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange 
    by self write
    by anonymous auth
    by set="[cn=Administrators,ou=group,dc=company,dc=com]/member* & user" manage
    by set="[cn=Domain Admins,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com]/memberUid* & user" manage
    by set="[cn=Operators,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com]/member* & user" read
    by * none

access to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange,sambaLMPassword,sambaNTPassword,displayName,description,givenName
    by anonymous auth
    by self =rwdx
    by set="[cn=Administrators,ou=group,dc=company,dc=com]/member* & user" manage
    by set="[cn=Domain Admins,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com]/memberUid* & user" manage
    by set="[cn=Operators,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com]/member* & user" read

access to dn.subtree="dc=company,dc=com"
    by self =rwdx
    by set="[cn=Administrators,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com]/member* & user" manage
    by set="[cn=Domain Admins,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com]/memberUid* & user" manage
    by set="[cn=Operators,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com]/member* & user" read
    by * break
```

I need to give Administrators and Domain Admins full rights and operators read access, with above settings even admins get read access.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my config to following and seems to be working for now

```
access to attrs=userPassword,sambaNTPassword,shadowLastChange
    by anonymous auth
    by self write
    by group.exact="cn=Administrators,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com" manage
    by group.exact="cn=Operators,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com" read

access to *
    by self write
    by dn.exact="uid=austek,ou=Technical,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com" manage
    by group.exact="cn=Administrators,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com" manage
    by group.exact="cn=Operators,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com" read
    by * break
```